# Can a static SqlDBConnection cause a thread to get another thread's result set?

Tags: asp.net, sqlconnection

While trying to debug an issue with an ASP.NET project, a coworker noticed that a method was instantiating a static SqlConnection.

If multiple threads are using that same SqlConnection concurrently, is it possible for one thread's SqlCommand to accidentally get the result set from another thread's SqlCommand?

For example, consider two concurrent requests to the same ASP.NET page:

Request 1:

```
Dim Shared DbConnection As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings("DbConnectionString"))
Dim Query As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand("EXEC up_ShowReportInMenu 'abc',...", DbConnection)
...
Dim Reader As SqlDataReader = Query.ExecuteReader
```

Request 2:

```
Dim Shared DbConnection As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings("DbConnectionString"))
Dim Query As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand("EXEC up_ShowReportInMenu 'def',...", DbConnection)
...
Dim Reader As SqlDataReader = Query.ExecuteReader
```

Is it possible that the Reader in Request 2 could accidentally access the result set from the query executed by the SqlCommand in Request 1?

P.S. Don't worry, we'll be changing this to not be static any more.  Just wondering if this could have possibly caused they problems we've been having.

Comment: @antlersoft - Any references you can point me to?  I didn't find anything definitive in my first Google attempt.

Answer (score 0):

According to [MSDN documentation for SqlConnection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.aspx):

*"Any public static (Shared in Visual Basic) members of this type are thread safe. Any instance members are not guaranteed to be thread safe."*

So yes, accessing the same `SqlConnection` instance from multiple threads would be a problem (even indirectly through `SqlCommand`s).

Comment: Yes, I'm aware that it could cause various exceptions.  I'm wondering in particular - could SqlCommand.ExecuteReader called from thread A return a SqlDataReader that points to a result set from a query that was  executed in thread B?

Comment: @mbeckish Worse than exceptions - this is undefined behavior and should be avoided no matter what, even if it appears to "work" in some specific circumstances and whether it appears to correctly throw exceptions in others. Whether the scenario you are describing is actually possible is a moot point this context.

Comment: Not really a moot point for us, since we can't definitively point to this as being the source of our bugs.  I already knew this was a bad practice - the point of this question was to see if anyone knew if this specific behavior was possible.

Comment: @mbeckish Of course it is possible. Undefined behavior can appear to "work", can fail in all sorts of ways, can print the works of Shakespeare or fetch you a coffee ;) Which one of these will actually happen? Nobody knows, it is undefined! The point I was trying to make is that it makes no sense to even ask the question until you fix the undefined behavior.

Comment: Not true.  The CLR is deterministic, after all.  I was looking for anyone who had actually experienced that behavior, or anyone familiar with the implementation of SqlConnection and SqlCommand who could expound upon how that behavior seems likely or unlikely.

Comment: @mbeckish OK, perhaps I got too poetical with the "C++esque" language, but honestly, what are you trying to accomplish here? Are you trying to see if you can get away without fixing the data race?

Comment: No, I'm not trying to justify using a static connection.  That's why I put the P.S. in the question - I was trying to avoid discussions around the pros/cons of static connections.  I'm just wondering specifically if anyone knows if a static connection can cause concurrent SQLCommands to receive the wrong result set.

Comment: @mbeckish From how client-server communication works, I can imagine a few reasons why this could happen. However, there is no purpose in speculating - I strongly suggest you fix the race **first** and then retest. If the problem goes away, you'll know for sure.

Comment: Speculation is exactly what I was hoping to avoid.  The problem is very rare, and not reproducible on demand.  Thanks anyway for your thoughts on this issue.